Can't search on List<KeyValuePair> saved as JSON string on DB using expression on ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework Core
I have table in my database which has a nullable string column ExtraInfo. Its value is JSON of List<KeyValuePair>, for example like this
{ "StaffCode": "123" }

As we added pagination for search we send filter as expression.
Here is my code:
public async Task<List<CusFinRequest>> GetDealsWithPagination(int organiztionId,string staffCode, int index, int size)
{
    var filter = PredicateBuilder.New<CusFinRequest>();
    
    if (organiztionId != default(int))
    {
        filter.And(x => x.Organization == organiztionId);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(staffCode))
    {
        filter.And(x => x.ExtraInfo != null &&
                        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(x.ExtraInfo).ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "StaffCode").Value == staffCode);
    }

    Func<IQueryable<CusFinRequest>, IOrderedQueryable<CusFinRequest>> orderBy = q => q.OrderByDescending(e => e.CreationDate);5

    return (await GetPaged(filter, orderBy, index, size, null, 0, "RequestHistory", "UserCart", "UserCart.BusinessLine")).ToList();
}

public async virtual Task<List<TEntity>> GetPaged(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
           Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
           int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = 0,
           string sortColumnName = "", int sortDirection = 0,
           params string[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (string include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
    }

    if (filter != null)
        query = query.Where(filter);

    if (orderBy != null)
        query = orderBy(query);

    if (pageIndex != default(int) && pageSize != default(int))
    {
        if (pageSize != -1) // Check if pageIndex is not -1 to retrieve all data
        {
            query = query.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

I got this issue after I looked for staff code.
I tried to update my expression to handle null keyvaluepair of Staffcode but I got a build error
{
  "StackTrace": " at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()\r\n at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at Ifin.Persistence.Repositories.BaseRepository`1.GetPaged(Expression`1 filter, Func`2 orderBy, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, String sortColumnName, Int32 sortDirection, String[] includes) in D:\\CoreProject\\Ifin.Repositories\\Repositories\\BaseRepository.cs:line 146\r\n at Ifin.Persistence.Repositories.CusFinRequestRepository.GetByAdvancedSearchPaginated(String customerId, String mobile, Nullable`1 BankId, String status, Int32 organiztionId, Nullable`1 startDate, Nullable`1 endDate, Nullable`1 maxAmount, Nullable`1 minAmount, String customerCIF, String staffCode, Int32 index, Int32 size) in D:\\CoreProject\\Ifin.Repositories\\Repositories\\CusFinRequestRepository.cs:line 91\r\n at Ifin.Business.Service.InquairyService.PaginatedSearch(Request`1 request) in D:\\CoreProject\\Ifin.Business\\Service\\InquairyService.cs:line 367\r\n at Ifin.Api.Controllers.InquiryController.PaginatedSearch(Request`1 request) in D:\\CoreProject\\Ifin.Api\\Controllers\\InquiryController.cs:line 77",
  "Message": "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<CusFinRequest>\r\n .Where(c => c.ExtraInfo == null ? False : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(c.ExtraInfo)\r\n  .Where(x => x.Key == \"StaffCode\")\r\n  .Select(s => s.Value)\r\n  .FirstOrDefault() == __staffCode_0 && c.Organization == __organiztionId_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpLink": null,
  "Source": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore",
  "HResult": -2146233079
}

from this
The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n .Where(c => c.ExtraInfo == null ? False : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(c.ExtraInfo)\r\n .Where(x => x.Key == "StaffCode")\r\n .Select(s => s.Value)\r\n .FirstOrDefault() == __staffCode_0 && c.Organization == __organiztionId_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I can understand that linq expression couldn't translated to find value by key in this JSON.
What is the right solution for this scenario?

You must map your model to JSON Columns and then query your model. Don't deserialize manually! (I never worked with Json columns myself, so I can't give you a full answer.)

So you mean it is better to find another way to save the data on DB  like create another table which contains StaffCode or any other data with one to one relationship from the main table  @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Json.NET (and System.Text.Json) will serialize a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> as a JSON array like so [{"Key":"some name","Value":"some value"}]  If your ExtraValue is a JSON object you need to use a Dictionary<string, string>.  Does that answer your question?

Also, I can't sell this from your code, but are you running your query on the server?  If so you can't use Json.NET (or any arbitrary function calls) because EF Code will be translating your expressions to SQL queries, and it certainly won't know how to do that for Json.NET calls.

What I mean is that you should create C# classes that can be mapped to your Json strings and then in OnModelCreating use ToJson to specify that you want this data in Json columns instead of another table. Then you can formulate your queries in terms of your entity classes. EF Core will do the Json-serialize/deserialize stuff for you.
